# Make 2 queries; one

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hello I'm a bit new to server commands so I was hoping anyone would give me a helping hand making this query.

I'm trying to insert data from 2 queries into a combo box but lack the knoledge to structure the query.

```
cmbGroups.RowSource = "Select GroupName, GroupNum from tblGroupHeader Where GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*' or GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"
cmbGroups.Requery
cmbGroups.SetFocus
cmbGroups.Dropdown

cmbGroups.RowSource = "Select Alsoknown, GroupNum from tblAlsoKnown"
```

I'd also like the groupNum from AlsoKnown to go under the same column as the GroupNum from GroupHeader. Is this possible?

I was testing a few things out and I think i'm close to an answer 
New query:

```
Select tblGroupHeader.GroupName, tblGroupHeader.GroupNum, tblAlsoKnown.AlsoKnown from tblGroupHeader INNER JOIN tblAlsoKnown ON tblGroupHeader.GroupNum = tblAlsoKnown.GroupNum Where GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*' or GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"
```

Comment: are those two tables related all? If not, then you should use two queries. doing a `join` query on unrelated tables is ugly/wrong on many levels.

Comment: Can you insert data twice into combobox without losing the first set of data? They are related by the GroupNum. GroupNum is primary key for tblGroupHeader and its one to many with alsoknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a join query as Marc B was implying:

```
cmbGroups.RowSource = "SELECT tblGroupHeader.GroupName" _
                           & ", tblGroupHeader.GroupNum" _
                           & ", tblAlsoKnown.AlsoKnown" _
                    & " FROM tblGroupHeader" _
                       & " LEFT JOIN tblAlsoKnown ON tblGroupHeader.GroupNum = tblAlsoKnown.GroupNum" _
                    & " WHERE tblGroupHeader.GroupName like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*'" _
                          & " OR tblGroupHeader.GroupNum like '" & txtgroupSearch.Value & "*';"

cmbGroups.Requery
cmbGroups.SetFocus
cmbGroups.Dropdown
```

Comment: If you run the query you suggested with the INNER JOIN or the LEFT JOIN that I included, then you don't need to put the "GroupNum" from tblAlsoKnown in addition to the "GroupNum" from tblGroupHeader as they are guaranteed to be the same.